# PersistenceManager does not persist the last entry in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, persistence-manager

first of all, i searched a lot but can't find a solution.

I wrote an Importer, which imports data from a xml file to TYPO3 via CommandController.

Basically everything works like charm, but the frontend does not display the second (and last) phonenumber, until i reopen the corresponding Object in the Backend and press "Save".

I did not change anything in the BE, just pressed "Save" once again.

What ive already tried:

Persist the datas more often, especially after adding the phoneNumbers(its a DataStorage Object).

with:

```
$this->thingsImportRepository->update($person);
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

As i said, everything is saved correctly, just the second phone number won't show up in the Frontend.

What could i have possibly done wrong?

Thanks!

BR,
Martin

Comment: If it's solved by just saving the record in the backend I suspect it is just the frontend cache. Have you tried clearing it manually via the backend? If that is the problem, you can use `DataHandler` in your importer to clear the cache of the certain page or cache tags where your data is shown.

Comment: Hi, i already solved the problem. Will post the solution as Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution basically just was a detail.

All data had been persisted correctly. At first i thought it was a cache-issue.

But:

***The Solution:***

The **sorting_foreign** property was not set correctly, so the sorting were everywhere 0. After saving it in the Backend the sorting was correctly numbered. Adding the `setForeignSorting($sort);` in the controller before persisting the object has fixed this issue